# Will Isomorphic app expose backend business logic?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, bundle, isomorphic-javascript

I have a question about isomorphic app(like next.js or sapper),
it is usually compiled as two bundles(one for client, another one for server) with Webpack or Rollup,
Then starting the server by running the bundle.

But are those bundles expose the business logic?

I wanna import my API secret key inside backend or hashing the user password, but will it be bundled into the client.bundle.js?

Comment: You should read the section on [environment variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables). It discusses this specifically.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense for the environment variables, but what about those logic? Is it still visible?

Comment: Like Sapper, it is this.fetch(), operations in it are invisible to client side.

Comment: There are some functions or hook like that are visible to client side and server side indeed, so I need to make sure I am using the server route to process some confidential operations that is only visible to server side.